# How to merge only Columns when both Rows and Columns are selected?

Tags: excel, ms-office

I want to merge only Columns in Excel when both Rows and Columns are selected.Is it possible?

Suppose I have selected 1,2 and 3 rows, want to merge A1-A2-A3 together and B1-B2-B3 together and so on.

Comment: There isn't a built in feature to do that, but it can be down with Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).

Comment: What about `Merge Across`?

Comment: Merge Across will merge each Row of the selected cells into a larger cell. I want to merge each Column of the selected cells in to a larger cell.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I read it all the way around. In this case I think you are left only with VBA:

```
Sub MergeColumns()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Selection.Column To Selection.Column + Selection.Columns.Count-1
        Range(Cells(Selection.Row, i), Cells(Selection.Row + Selection.Rows.Count-1, i)).Merge
    Next i
End Sub
```

EDIT:
Sorry my bad, I left switched row-column indexes for cells. Now it is corrected.

Comment: Merge Across will merge each Row of the selected cells into a larger cell. I want to merge each Column of the selected cells in to a larger cell.

Comment: Sub MacroMergeNew()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Selection.Rows To Selection.Rows + Selection.Rows.Count - 1
        Range(Cells(Selection.Column, i), Cells(Selection.Column + Selection.Column.Count - 1, i)).Merge
    Next i
End Sub

Comment: Thanks @arabisays, now it is corrected following your comments.